# Printing corresponding rows from dataframe for items in list - Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I am trying to automate a report I do daily. I have a an excel spreadsheet and have to pull information out it to format it in a specific way. There are columns: `'Invoice', 'Name', 'Address', 'PO #', 'Product', 'Lot', and 'Quantity'`.

First, I need to the information grouped by 'Invoice'. For each invoice, the name, address and PO# need to be stated. Under that information, each of the products lines separately.

Using `groupby` in pandas, I am able to group most of the information by invoice and product, but this doesn't provide the format I need. I have also tried putting the invoice column in a list and doing a for loop to cycle through each of the invoice numbers, but when I iterate in the loop, it just prints all the products for every invoice.

Since I work with mostly `R` and `MySQL`, I feel like I need to use a where statement regarding the list but I am not sure how to do that in a loop. I am also not sure how to achieve the goal of printing the other information such as name, address and PO# under the invoice.

The `groupby` that doesn't give the right format and also sums qty, when it is not needed.

```py
group_inv_pro = df.groupby(['Invoice', 'Product', 'Lot'])['Quantity'].sum()
print(group_inv_pro)
```

The loop I have tried to build. This gives every product for each invoice.

```py
invoices = df['Invoice'].drop_duplicates().tolist()

for invoice in invoices:
     print("Invoice: " + str(invoice))
     for invoice, row in df.iterrows():
         print(row['Product'] + " "  + str(row['Lot']) + " " + str(row['Quantity']))
```

The report I am trying to produce has the following information in this format:

```
Invoice:

Name:

Address:

PO#:

Product     Lot      Quantity
```

[Desired Report Format Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp6An.png)

Here is the example dataframe for convenience

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'Invoice':[632, 632, 632, 633, 633, 634, 634, 634],
     'Name':['Jason', 'Jason', 'Jason', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Jessica', 'Jessica', 'Jessica'], 
     'Address':['76 Berry Lane', '76 Berry Lane', '76 Berry Lane', '62 Star Dr.', '62 Star Dr.', 
                '28 Jefferson', '28 Jefferson', '28 Jefferson'],
     'PO #':[46, 46, 46, 24, 24, 23, 23, 23],
     'Product':['ZDA89', 'KLP65', 'TYW85', 'ZDA89', 'PLW36', 'KLP65', 'PLW36', 'PLW36'],
     'Lot':[56, 68, 14, 56, 90, 68, 90, 101],
     'Quantity':[2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 9, 4, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[Example Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWtkg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the following:

```
for invoice_no in df['Invoice'].unique():
    df1 = df[df['Invoice']== invoice_no]
    print(f"Invoice: {invoice_no}")
    print(f"Name: {df1['Name'].values[0]}")
    print(f"Address: {df1['Address'].values[0]}")
    print(f"Po: {df1['PO #'].values[0]}")
    print(df1[['Product','Lot','Quantity']].set_index('Product'))
    print("")
```

It will work for basic printing. I am assuming you are not using html, but just to automate the process, hence suggesting this.

```
Invoice: 632
Name: Jason
Address: 76 Berry Lane
Po: 46
         Lot  Quantity
Product               
ZDA89     56         2
KLP65     68         1
TYW85     14         1

Invoice: 633
Name: Sam
Address: 62 Star Dr.
Po: 24
         Lot  Quantity
Product               
ZDA89     56         3
PLW36     90         3

Invoice: 634
Name: Jessica
Address: 28 Jefferson
Po: 23
         Lot  Quantity
Product               
KLP65     68         9
PLW36     90         4
PLW36    101         4
```

In fact I think the table df should only store ClientId, instead of the common info like name, address and PO #. Then in each loop, you should call based on the Client Id to pull out client's info.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So I was over thinking this then, cause this works perfectly for printing the report. I actually have to export this to excel, and I am able to do that except for the dataframe in the line. I have tried converting df1 to a string, but of course that just prints it as one long line instead of retaining the dataframe structure. Do you have any other ideas to re write that line to get it to export the structure correctly?

Comment: what kind of structure do you wish to get? One invoice per csv? Because one invoice per csv will not give meaningful structure. It is more of displaying the need data line by line instead of having a table-like structure

Comment: This layout for the report is exactly how the department head wants the information. I currently receive the information in a messy excel file from our warehouse and then I manually clean it and format it in excel. I am learning python and thought this would have been a good project to tackle. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Nice to know that you are using python in real life and hope it helps you to automate the routine processes. Don't be afraid to ask and good luck.